# removing "The " from array values to order alphabetically

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array in which every value starts with a name of a venue. Some venues have a "The " in front of them which I want to remove so that when I `sort()` the array I don't end up with all the "The ..." venues at the "T".

I wrote this:

```
function remove_The($array) {
    global $all_venue_listings;
    // remove the "The" from the listings...
    foreach($all_venue_listings as $v) {
        if ( substr($v, 0, 4) === "The " || substr($v, 0, 4) === "the " || substr($v, 0, 4) === "THE " ) {
            $v = preg_replace("/The /i","",$v);
        }
    }
    return $all_venue_listings;
}
```

But that doesn't seem to put the changed values back into the array. How can I operate on the array in the `foreach` loop so that what I change goes back into the original array?

I tried replacing the `preg_replace` line with this:

```
$all_venue_listings[] = preg_replace("/The /i","",$v);
```

But that just creates a duplicate entry in the array (one with "The " and one without).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options.

1) Use a reference and update the element directly (note the `&`):

```
foreach($all_venue_listings as &$v) {
...
$v = ...
```

2) Use a key and update the original array:

```
foreach($all_venue_listings as $key => $v) {
...
$all_venue_listings[$key] = ...
```

Either will work. I prefer #1